# Ruby map nested array

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, dictionary

I have this string that I'm trying split into nested arrays:

```
x = '{type:paragaph|class:red|content:[class:intro|body:This is the introduction paragraph.][body:This is the second paragraph.]}'
x << '{type:image|class:grid|content:[id:1|title:image1][id:2|title:image2][id:3|title:image3]}'
```

This so far:

```
x.scan(/\{(.*?)\}/).map {|m| m[0].split(/\|\s*(?=[^\[\]]*(?:\[|$))/)}
```

successfully divides it into:

```
[
  ["type:paragaph", "class:red", "content:[class:intro|body:This is the introduction paragraph.][body:This is the second paragraph.]"],
  ["type:image", "class:grid", "content:[id:1|title:image1][id:2|title:image2][id:3|title:image3]"]
]
```

---

I'm trying to add an additional map:

```
x.scan(/\{(.*?)\}/).map {|m| m[0].split(/\|\s*(?=[^\[\]]*(?:\[|$))/)}.map {|m| m[0].split(/\:\s*(?=[^\[\]]*(?:\[|$))/)}
```

which returns:

```
[["type", "paragaph"], ["type", "image"]]
```

however I am after this instead:

```
[
  [['type','paragaph'], ['class','red'], ['content',['[class:intro|body:This is the introduction paragraph.][body:This is the second paragraph.]']],
  [['type','image'], ['class','grid'], ['content','[id:1|title:image1][id:2|title:image2][id:3|title:image3]']]
]
```

The map appears to be applying itself to the whole 2nd level array instead of each element inside it. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second map you your are splitting only the first element instead of spliting every element with a map

```
x.scan(/\{(.*?)\}/).map {|m| m[0].split(/\|\s*(?=[^\[\]]*(?:\[|$))/)}.map {|m| m.map {|n| n.split(/\:\s*(?=[^\[\]]*(?:\[|$))/)}}
```

Also you could clean it up a little extracting the regex into a variable

```
regex = /\|\s*(?=[^\[\]]*(?:\[|$))/

x.scan(/\{(.*?)\}/).map {|m| m[0].split(regex)}.map {|m| m.map {|n| n.split(regex)}}
```